# Is it valid to call c# extension methods in a static context?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, coded-ui-tests

I'm working on coded UI and was playing with extension methods and found something interesting. I had an extension method

```
public static bool Click (this UITestElement Element)
{//Code to Click Element and log any errors to framework logger}
```

I later without thinking called in another method

```
UITestElement Element = new UITestElement();
//Code to located element
Click(Element);
```

And the compiler didn't complain. I was just curious, is this usage valid, or will I get a runtime error?

Comment: You refer to "C# extension methods". It doesn't matter which language the extension method is written in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how extension methods work in the background, at compile time their *instance* looking call gets converted into static method call.

There will not be any runtime error.

See: [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb383977.aspx)

> In your code you invoke the extension method with instance method
>   syntax. **However, the intermediate language (IL) generated by the
>   compiler translates your code into a call on the static method.**

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods are nothing more than static methods inside static classes, which are bound to instance method calls at compile time when the first parameter is prefixed with `this`. You can still treat them as static methods on a static class like you would any other. Hence, this will work.

An example. Given this code:

```
void Main()
{
    int i = 0;
    i.Foo();
}

public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static int Foo(this int i)
    {
        return i;
    }
}
```

The compiler will emit the following IL (optimization turned off):

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // i
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // i
IL_0004:  call        IntExtensions.Foo
IL_0009:  pop         
IL_000A:  ret
```

As you can see, the actual instruction which invokes the method (IL_0004) emits a `call` to the static method on the actual static class.